# Is there a way to get a report of suppressed lint messages?

Tags: c, static-analysis, lint, suppress-warnings, pc-lint

I am using PC-Lint Plus and suppressing few lint warnings throughout the source code. Is there a way in PC-Lint Plus to get a report of line numbers (or file names) where someone has suppressed warnings for software risk analysis ? This will help evaluate if some ignored/suppressed warnings have good reasons to ignore/suppress or should be handled.

Comment: PC-Lint Plus seem to be a commercial software. They should have support for such a questions. OTOH I would imagine such a feature quite obsolete, as suppressing warnings is for not seeing them anywhere in reports. If you want to see them - don't suppress.

Comment: Some coding guidelines requires that all deviations are documented, e.g. MISRA C. So these kinds of reports are quite common in some industries.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of. But it's quite easy to write a script in your favourite scripting language to search for `/*lint` and `//lint`. If you have a rationale in the comment you can also extract that and include it in the report. If you want to be extra fancy you could even match the warning number to e.g. MISRA rules. It's a fun little exercise if you like writing scripts.